# How to import multiple bands from an image into numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, gdal

I'm new to python/numpy. I need to import *n* bands of data (~125) from a multiband image into an *n*-dimensional array. Each value is a 16-bit signed integer. Currently I have python code that looks like this:

```
stream = bytearray()

mbImage = open(filename, mode='rb'); 

while curr <= filesize: 
    mbImage.seek(curr)
    b = mbImage.read(samples * 2)
    stream += b 
    curr += (2 * bands * samples)
```

How can I convert this code to numpy, so that I can do this for each band? I tried the following, which doesn't work (this includes gdal):

```
npBandArr = np.array(inDs.GetRasterBand(10).ReadAsArray())
```

Answer (score 3):

GDAL already returns a Numpy array, so wrapping `np.array` is unnecessary.

If you want to read all bands in the dataset, you can skip selecting the bands one at a time and use:

`data = ds.ReadAsArray()`

The first dimension of the array are the bands (check with `print(data.shape)`).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the process of taking multiple band using gdal

```
import gdal
import numpy as np
dataset= gdal.Open(r"AnnualCrop_1.tif")
myarray1 = np.array(dataset.GetRasterBand(number of bands you want ).ReadAsArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to loop through all the bands in a raster dataset as a numpy array. You can get the number of bands in gdal dataset using `GDALDataset.RasterCount`.

For example, this would read data from each band into an array.

```
ds = gdal.Open("path to some file")
for band in range( ds.RasterCount ):
    band += 1
    nparray = ds.GetRasterBand(band).ReadAsArray()
```

If you want to store the data in an array, you could initialize a 3d array with then number of rows, columns, and bands in the dataset.