# How to read multiband image files with more than 4 bands in python?

Tags: python, arrays, image, multidimensional-array, gdal

I am using the following code to read geotiff images (~300). Each image file contains 15 bands.

code:

```
import gdal
inputPath="/content/drive/MyDrive/Notebook/test/tiled_stack"
images = []
# Load in the images
for filepath in os.listdir(inputPath):
    images.append(gdal.Open(inputPath+'/{0}'.format(filepath)))
    image = images.ReadAsArray()

print(type(images[1]))
```

error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ReadAsArray'
```

Another code from [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218338/running-script-over-every-file-in-folder-using-gdal-in-python):

```
myImages= glob.glob(os.path.join(inputPath, '*.tif'))
for data_path in myImages:
  images=gdal.Open(data_path, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)

type(images)
osgeo.gdal.Dataset
```

How can I modify the code to resolve the error and have images in form of (width, height, number of bands)?

Comment: What is the type and format of your 15 bands image? Can you share a sample image?

Comment: The images are in geotiff format. The example of this image files can be found: [https://github.com/phelber/eurosat#paper] and can be download from this text in that page: "EuroSAT Dataset (MS)"

Comment: The problem you are encountering has nothing to do with the image having more or less than 4 bands.

Comment: The "another code from this link" obviously has a missing closing parenthesis. You should not blindly execute code you found on the internet.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I previously used open cv and pillow to load these images, to my knowledge, they only read RGB and RGBA. That's why I mentioned more than 4 bands in the title of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may read the image using GDAL as described in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43684072/how-to-import-multiple-bands-from-an-image-into-numpy).

Example:

```
import gdal

filepath = r'c:\Tmp\ds\images\remote_sensing\otherDatasets\sentinel_2\tif\Forest\Forest_1.tif'

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43684072/how-to-import-multiple-bands-from-an-image-into-numpy
# Load one GeoTIFF image using GDAL
dataset = gdal.Open(filepath)
image = dataset.ReadAsArray()

print(type(image))  # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(image.shape)  # (13, 64, 64)
print(image.dtype)  # uint16
```

---

Installing GDAL in Windows is not so straight forward.

I started working by the following [instructions](https://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/tutorials/installing-gdal-for-windows), but it's not up to date.

I downloaded `gdal-204-1911-x64-core.msi` and `GDAL-2.4.4.win-amd64-py3.6.msi` (matches Python 3.6) from [here](https://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1911-x64-gdal-2-4-4-mapserver-7-4-3.zip).

I updated the environment variables with `C:\Program Files` opposed to `C:\Program Files (x86)` (as described in the instructions).

For some reason it's working only when I **Run** the Python script, but gives an error when I **Debug** the script.

---

### Update:

`images` is a Python list.
You can't use `images.ReadAsArray()`, because Python list has no method `ReadAsArray()`.

You may append an image to the list after executing `image = dataset.ReadAsArray()` - you have to call the method for every image, and can't apply it to the list.

Example:

```
import gdal

inputPath="/content/drive/MyDrive/Notebook/test/tiled_stack"
images = []

# Load the images, and append them to a list.
for filepath in os.listdir(inputPath):
    dataset = gdal.Open(inputPath+'/{0}'.format(filepath))
    image = dataset.ReadAsArray()  # Returned image is a NumPy array with shape (13, 64, 64) for example.
    images.append(image)  # Append the NumPy array to the list.
    
print(type(images[1]))
```

Comment: I am running the code in google colab. I updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: I updated my answer. I can't test is right now (because I don't have GDAL installation). In case I missed something... please make an effort to understand my explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  When I run `print(np.shape(images[1]))`, this returns  `(15, 16, 16)` , Is it possible to change it to  `(16, 16, 15)`?. In addition, after splitting the train and test data by `(trainY, testY, trainX, testX) = train_test_split(df, images, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)`, the size of `trainX` is `(159,)` , may I know how I should change it to  `(159, 16, 16, 15)` ?

Comment: I added `rearranged_images = np.transpose(images, axes=[0, 2, 3, 1])` to reorder the images to (16, 16, 15). This also solved trainX issue.